# NSTextField will not update

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

```
[self.change setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", changeValue]];
```

where change is an IBOutlet of type NSTextField.  For whatever reason I can not get the text field to display anything I want.  Every time I run, the field is "0".  Any ideas on why it won't change?

Comment: Try logging both self.change and changeValue to see what they give you.

Comment: Should have mentioned this before.  changeValue is fine (int).  self.change gives me the object and self.change.stringValue is the same as changeValue

Comment: Do you have any other code that would affect this text field? Any delegate methods implemented?

Comment: one step closer I think... from all of my debugging I was using the awakeFromNib function which set it to 0.  I was able to set the string to whatever in this method.  I removed the method and now nothing shows.  How do set the string from another method?

Comment: You should be able to put the line of code you posted in any method that gets called, and it should work.  I can't say where without knowing the structure of your app.

Comment: You are correct.  I've realized where I went wrong, just need to come up with a the right way to do it and will report back.

Comment: You don't need to set string value for `NSTextField` if you are setting int value. You can do it simply like this:

    `[self.change setIntValue:changeValue];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is the embarrassing rookie mistake for others to learn from.  I was calling my setstringvalue before the view was even loaded; in the didfinishlaunching method.  Use the awakefromnib method to make sure you view is loaded. Via Apple:

```
Finally, after all the objects are fully initialized, each receives an awakeFromNib message.
```

Comment: This should work in applicationDidFinishLaunching: (which is called after awakeFromNib). How are you loading your view? Are you loading it explicitly or is it just in the main window of the app?

Comment: main window of the app.  I thought didfinish should work also... I'm confused haha.

Answer (score 3):

Never update textfield or pop-button in init. You have to fill default values in awakeFromNib or some other delegates once class gets initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the outlet is really linked with the NSTextField you have put in the xib file.

Comment: Verified I believe http://imgur.com/CpKOy.  It's probably something really dumb that I didn't do.